# Failed to load angular.mock.module

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I am currently learning to write unit tests and I am trying to make some unit tests for the [Ui-Router Sample app](https://github.com/ui-router/sample-app-angularjs).

Unfortunately the **angular.mock.module** won't load the main module.

*Because of **typescript** and **browserify** karma can read the files properly.*

---

This is the error:

```
Angular Main Module
    ✗ should exist
    Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module demo due to:
    Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'demo' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/$injector/nomod?p0=demo
        at /home/jarno/Desktop/ui-router-sample-app-ng1-master/node_modules/angular/angular.js:68:12
        at /home/jarno/Desktop/ui-router-sample-app-ng1-master/node_modules/angular/angular.js:2101:17
        at ensure (/home/jarno/Desktop/ui-router-sample-app-ng1-master/node_modules/angular/angular.js:2025:38)
        at module (/home/jarno/Desktop/ui-router-sample-app-ng1-master/node_modules/angular/angular.js:2099:14)
        at /home/jarno/Desktop/ui-router-sample-app-ng1-master/node_modules/angular/angular.js:4607:22
        at forEach (/home/jarno/Desktop/ui-router-sample-app-ng1-master/node_modules/angular/angular.js:322:20)
        at loadModules (/home/jarno/Desktop/ui-router-sample-app-ng1-master/node_modules/angular/angular.js:4591:5)
        at Object.createInjector [as injector] (/home/jarno/Desktop/ui-router-sample-app-ng1-master/node_modules/angular/angular.js:4513:19)
        at Object.workFn (/home/jarno/Desktop/ui-router-sample-app-ng1-master/node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3060:52)
```

**app/bootstrap/ngmodule.js**

```
/**
 * This file imports the third party library dependencies, then creates the angular module "demo"
 * and exports it.
 */

// External dependencies
import * as angular from "angular";
import uiRouter from "@uirouter/angularjs";
import {visualizer} from "@uirouter/visualizer";

// Create the angular module "demo".
//
// Since it is exported, other parts of the application (in other files) can then import it and register things.
// In bootstrap.js, the module is imported, and the components, services, and states are registered.
export const ngmodule = angular.module("demo", [uiRouter]);

// Show ui-router-visualizer
ngmodule.run($uiRouter => visualizer($uiRouter));

const BLANK_MODULE = {
  states: [],
  components: {},
  directives: {},
  services: {},
  filters: {},
  configBlocks: [],
  runBlocks: []
};

/**
 * Register each app module's states, directives, components, filters, services,
 * and config/run blocks with the `ngmodule`
 *
 * @param ngModule the `angular.module()` object
 * @param appModule the feature module consisting of components, states, services, etc
 */
export function loadNg1Module(ngModule, appModule) {

  let module = Object.assign({}, BLANK_MODULE, appModule);


  ngModule.config(['$stateProvider', $stateProvider => module.states.forEach(state => $stateProvider.state(state))]);

  Object.keys(module.components).forEach(name => ngModule.component(name, module.components[name]));

  Object.keys(module.directives).forEach(name => ngModule.directive(name, module.directives[name]));

  Object.keys(module.services).forEach(name => ngModule.service(name, module.services[name]));

  Object.keys(module.filters).forEach(name => ngModule.filter(name, module.filters[name]));

  module.configBlocks.forEach(configBlock => ngModule.config(configBlock));

  module.runBlocks.forEach(runBlock => ngModule.run(runBlock));

  return ngModule;
}
```

**tests/ngmodule.spec.js**

```
describe('Angular Main Module', function() {

  var AuthService;

  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('demo'));

  beforeEach(inject(function(_AuthService_) {
    AuthService = _AuthService_;
  }));

  it('should exist', function() {
    expect(AuthService).toBeDefined();
  });


})
```

**karma.conf.js**

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'browserify'],
    files: [
      './node_modules/angular/angular.js',
      './node_modules/@uirouter/angularjs/release/angular-ui-router.js',
      './node_modules/@uirouter/visualizer/bundles/visualizer.min.js',
      './node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      {pattern: './transpiled/app/**/*.map.js', included: true, watched: true, served: true},
      {pattern: './tests/**/*.js', included: true, watched: true, served: true}
    ],
    exclude: [
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      'transpiled/app/**/*.map.js': [ 'browserify' ]
    },
    reporters: ['spec'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "ui-router-architecture",
  "description": "Architecture overview demo for Angular UI-Router",
  "version": "1.0.2",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run watch:compile & npm run serve",
    "compile": "./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc",
    "watch:compile": "./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc -w",
    "serve": "lite-server",
    "build": "babel app -d lib",
    "gh-pages": "git checkout gh-pages && git rebase master && rm -rf node_modules && npm install && echo 'If there are any updated modules:' && echo 'git commit -am update_libs' && echo 'git rebase -i' && echo && echo 'Finally:' && echo 'git push origin gh-pages:gh-pages --force' && echo 'git checkout master'"
  },
  "contributors": [
    {
      "name": "Chris Thielen",
      "web": "https://github.com/christopherthielen"
    }
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/ui-router/sample-app.git"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@uirouter/visualizer": "^4.0.0",
    "@uirouter/angularjs": "^1.0.0",
    "angular": "1.5.6",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "d3": "^3.5.16",
    "font-awesome": "^4.5.0",
    "systemjs": "^0.19.24",
    "systemjs-plugin-css": "^0.1.20",
    "typescript": "^1.8.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "1.5.6",
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.5.1",
    "browserify": "^14.4.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
    "karma": "^0.13.22",
    "karma-browserify": "^5.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.26",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "watchify": "^3.9.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: I dont think any of the items in the `files` property in the karma.conf.js map to app/bootstrap/ngmodule.js

Comment: @Bowofola Please take a look at my edited post: Package.json file. Because of the npm start command all the files become converted into the transpiled folder. Do you still think I'm not mapping my files correctly?

Comment: do you run `npm start` before trying to run the tests?

Comment: @Bowofola Yes. I tried adding a seperate testfile into the transpiled folder with a Angular.module('demo2', []); but the testfile doesn't recognize the module either.

Comment: Why would they be *.map.js and not *.js? Any way, it's not about Angular, the problem is in configuration. It may be wrong path or something else. You are the only person who can figure out what's wrong, the question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . The app doesn't look like https://github.com/ui-router/sample-app-angularjs at all, it doesn't use Webpack.

Comment: I changed it from .map.js to .js now and it gives this error: Uncaught Error: bundle error (see logs)
  at /tmp/38166bde481df1f1e01914bc42f016d1.browserify:1

Chrome 56.0.2924 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.109 secs / 0 secs)

Comment: @estus Okay so I assume I was using a deprecated UI-Router sample app. I am now using the latest one from that link and it gives the same error as in my question.

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it by using the latest version. Was still using Demo2 (a testfile) instead of demo.